# Exploring a graph with loops, issue with member predicate

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to explore a graph that may have loops so i have to put nodes that i already "visited" in an array.
The issue is that Prolog tells me that member(Y,Ys) is true thus the predicate fails... 
I know that there exists some arrays such that `member(Y,Ys)` holds but why Prolog doesn't search for an other solution?

```
 tauReachable(X,Defs,[Y|Ys]) :-
    trans(X,tau,Defs,Y),
    not(member(Y,Ys)), 
    tauReachable(X,Defs,Ys).
 tauReachable(_X,_Defs,[]) :- !.
```

(trans: X is the initial node, tau is the arc label, Defs nothing important, Y is the arrival node)

Answer (score 0):

I've done it in this way:

```
 tauReachable(X,Defs,Y) :-
    tauReachableR(X,Defs,Y,[X]),
    !.
 tauReachableR(X,Defs,Y,Z) :-
    trans(X,tau,Defs,F),
    not(member(F,Z)),
    !, 
    append([F],Z,S),
    tauReachableR(X,Defs,Y,S).
 tauReachableR(X,Defs,Z,Z).
```